Linux directories for App (create package)
I'm creating a Linux version of a Windows program and among other tasks, I need to create a package to allow users to install the software easily.
In Windows, the program has some files in the following folders:

Program files: c:\Program Files\company_name\my_app
Program data: c:\ProgramData\company_name\my_app
User content: c:\Users\TheUserName\Documents\company_name\my_app

In Linux, I know that User-related content should be placed in "/home/TheUserName/Documents/company_name/my_app"
But I don't know exactly where to place "Program files" and "Program data": /usr/share, /usr/bin, /var, /etc/...?
What is the most appropriate location to place the files?
Should I copy the binary files to the specific folder or should I create a folder for the program?
There are also some shared SO libraries, so should I copy them to /usr/lib? /usr/share? To any other location?
Finally, I would mainly work with Debian or Ubuntu distributions, so what do you recommend, a DEB,  a flatpack package or something else?
I hope anyone can help with this. Any clue, document, guide, etc will be much appreciated.

You seem to be confused about how things work in the Linux file system. If you install into the user's home directory then all the components should be installed in the user's home directory; but if you are looking for a system-wide install (such as a .deb package) all of the files should go into system locations. The Debian packaging documentation has all the details (maybe start at https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) but in brief, the binary would go in /usr/bin/my_app, binary library files in /usr/lib, and the data in /usr/share/lib/my-app or some such.

... But use debhelper etc and you don't even have to know very much about this.

I frankly cannot see any advantage with alternate package formats if your target is Debian / Ubuntu.

@tripleee Maybe I didn't explained it properly. I meant that user-related files (like saved documents) should go to the /home folder, but not software-related files. When you refer to /usr/bin/my_app, "my_app" means the binary file or a folder?

The package manager cannot do that, but your software should probably be creating those at run time for each user who uses the software, not at install time.

Thank you @tripleee. I guess you refer to the /home files, in that case, the software will create them for each user. But about the /usr/bin/my_app location. Is it normal to create a company folder like /usr/bin/company and then put all the company related programs there?

No, the binary should be directly in /usr/bin in order to be available on the PATH for all users. Some nontrivial packages might install their files somewhere else and then just install symlinks to the executables in /usr/bin

Anyway, the package manager will take care of these things for you, as long as you follow the packaging instructions.
